# Is it possible to have 2 activities in Delphi Android project, where does the second activity show a simple form after run?

Tags: android, delphi, android-activity, delphi-10.2-tokyo

Is it possible to have one standard activity (`com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity`) and another FMX-based activity in one Delphi Android project, where does the second activity show a simple form after run?

Comment: You can have only one FMXNativeActivity in a Delphi Android app. You might be able to create an app with a second activity, but it would likely need to be in Java. It might help to illustrate exactly what you're attempting to achieve

Comment: I'm trying to create my own application that will replace the existing (built-in) application with the call. I've done everything. I just need to create a separate form for receiving and sending a call when needed

Comment: You may need to be more specific about "done everything" and "the call"

Comment: Application us complete prepared without showing form for incoming call and touchpad for dualing call. I need to show (create) these two forms using separately activity.

Comment: It may be just a simple matter of including the second activity in the manifest, and calling startActivity from the other one (using TAndroidHelper.Context.startActivity). I'm not sure if this would work as I've never tried it

Comment: In Android Studio it is very simple. But I need to do it in Delphi.